# Erro File not found ao mover imagem no Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

Estou tentando mover uma imagem que está localizada dentro de `storage/temp` para `storage/app/public/erro_log` com o método `Storage::move();`, porem recebo o erro de `File not found`, mesmo a imagem estando no local de origem.

Para o teste acabei isolando o método:

```
Storage::move(storage_path('temp/erro.png'), storage_path('app/spublic/erro_log/123.png'));
```

**Print do erro:**
[image: Erro print]

Em resumo ao mover a imagem para outro destino estou recebendo o erro dizendo que ela não existe mesmo ela estando no local do log, (apenas copio e colo o caminho no terminal que a imagem abre).

**@EDIT**
Testei seguindo a mesma lógica no Linux e gerou o mesmo erro de `File not found`.

Agradeço toda a qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Acredito que você deve configurar o disk que você utilizará para salvar, mover, etc... no arquivo `root_folder\config\filesystems.php`. Seguindo a [documentção](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem)

Comment: Acabei resolvendo o problema, porem não achei como mudar esse parâmetro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fazendo os testes acabei solucionando o problema, pelo que entendi a função  `storage_path();` e o método `Storage::move();` por padrão eles já trabalham dentro do diretório `storage/`.

Por exemplo, para mover um um arquivo do diretório `temp` para o diretório `app` comando seria:

```
Storage::move('temp/test.png', '/app/test.png');
```

No caso o caminho passado é o relativo não o caminho completo `var/www/html...` 
Isso vale para o `Storage::delete();` e provavelmente para todos os outros.